# Which Beautiful Soup version is included in XBMC?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xbmc

I am trying to do some website scraping in Python in combination with XBMC. When I look at the website of Beautiful Soup the latest version is version 4. When I look at XBMC it says version 3.2.0 (http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on:BeautifulSoup)

Does anyone now which version is used in XBMC?

Comment: On the XBMC forum they say it is 3.2.1: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=174201&pid=1513469#pid1513469

Answer (score 0):

On the XBMC forum they say it is 3.2.1: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=174201&pid=1513469#pid1513469